# Yii2 hide Autogenerated Column in Gridview

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I created a Gridview widget but I have extra column labeled by # mark and it's same the primary key value. I don't know how I can delete it. I don't find any column related to it in my code .

Geriview was generated by Gii and I used PAjax in it.

[image]

This is my gridview code

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
        <?= GridView::widget([
        'id'=>'files',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'f_id',
                [
                'attribute' => 'type',
                'value' => function($model){
                        return \app\models\Files::getIconOfExtension($model->type);
                },
                'format' => 'raw',
                'filter'=>false,
                ],

                'original_name',
                'file_title',
                [
                'attribute'=>'upload_date',
                'value'=>'upload_date',
        //      'filter' =>\yii\jui\DatePicker::widget(['language' => \app\components\MyGlobalClass::getLanguage(), 'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy']),
                'format' => 'html',
                ],

                [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{download} {view} {update} {delete}',
                'buttons' => [
                        'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>', ['update', 'id'=>$model->file_code],['title'=>\Yii::t('app','Update')]);
                        },
                        'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>', ['view', 'id'=>$model->file_code],['title'=>\Yii::t('app','View')]);
                        },
                        'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['delete', 'id'=>$model->file_code],['title'=>\Yii::t('app','Delete')]);
                        },
                        'download' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>', ['download', 'id'=>$model->file_code],['title'=>\Yii::t('app','Download')]);
                        },
                ],
                ],





                ],
        ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following as per the requirement:

```
     Remove the code ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
```